# Separate Profit and Loss Numbers From One Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, forex

I have imported data from an outside source into Excel.  The data comes as "Profit" in one single column.  However, it contains both profit and loss numbers. In order to provide a true analysis, I must be able to separate the data and recognize which cells are profit and which are losses.  Below are screenshots of two different sheets of what I have developed so far, but hit a road block.

[image]
[image]

I am trying to take the profit/loss in Column R from the top picture, and calculate these on spreadsheet to (4 Hour) results for G8 & I8 on the bottom picture.  If I can do this, all other calculations will be successful.  I have not been able to get this to operate properly.  Any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: What formula is it that you have in there now that is not working for you?  how do you want the values in in G8 and I 8 to be calculated?  Did you look at the SUMIF/SUMIFS formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumptions are that a) cell formatting has been applied to remove the - from negative numbers and colour them red. And b) loss is negative and profit is positive.

Based on the fixed ranges of the example supplied, profit is calculated by:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B11,">=0",B2:B11)
```

And loss is calculated by:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B11,"<=0",B2:B11)
```

Test workings:

[image]

Comment: You could also SUMIF on the column that says profit loss.  I was awaiting clarification on which numbers to use, because this also appears to be a four hour windows which could be 4 hours before the time, after the time, centered on the time.  As such I think a SUMIFS may be eventually required.

Comment: My desire is to split the Profit/Loss column from the top picture (Column Q) into two different fields in the lower picture (G8 & I8).   Does this help?

Comment: @BrianWhite - my answer gives separate results for total profit and total loss, based on the example you provided. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @ForwardEd - understood - I just went ahead and provided the SUMIF example for the profit/ loss column in the example.

Comment: Based on what you have suggested, here is the formula that I intended to use for loss... =SUMIF(Results!R10:R204,"<=0",Results!R10:R204).  However, this will not work.  I see the idea, but not sure how to draw / total that entire column (Q) into one total for loss.

Comment: =SUMIF('4Hour'!R10:R204,"<0",'4Hour'!R10:R204) - solution for loss

Comment: =SUMIF('4Hour'!R10:R204,">=0",'4Hour'!R10:R204) - solution for profit